# Android string regular expression not working

Tags: android, regex

Good evening! 
I have incoming string paramert, something like that "522|625|925|...6234|"
I create regular string such look. "([0-9]\|)*"
introduce pattern to app and...

```
 public static String decrypt( String message, int incr ) {
    String result = "";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]\\|)*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
    boolean look = matcher.lookingAt();    
    if (look) {
        Log.d("MyActivity","exist: " + message);
```

i can see row "exist: niiice" at the log cat.
What I'm made wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\|{1})+");
```

"*" quantifier in your pattern means **zero** or more times, so matcher.lookingAt() return true on any input string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Changing the `*` to `+` is correct, but why did you add the `{1}`?  You know that doesn't do anything, don't you?